# Carry Forward Rounding

Tags: clickhouse

I have set of arrays

```
    [0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21] as a,
    [0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31] as b,
    [0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48] as c
```

If you notice, a1+b1+c1 = 1 (where a1 is the first element of array a). 
I want to implement a rounding wherein the answer is

```
    [0, 0, 1, 0] for a
    [0, 1, 0, 0] for b
    [1, 0, 0, 1] for c
```

Step 1. 
Do a round function for a1, b1, c1 -> this will give us a value of a1=0, b1=0 and c1=0 (resulting in a carryforward value of 0.21, 0.31 and 0.48 for next set of values i.e., a2, b2, and c2.

Step 2. 
However since after Step 1, the  round(a1) + round(b1) + round(c1) < a1+b1+c1, the idea is to roundup the element that got rounded down the maximum (so that we get the rounded sum equal to sum of unrounded values) and then carry forward the excess to decrement from the next value.

For e.g.
after the first allocation, c1 will get rounded up to 1 (getting an excess of 0.52 which we should decrement from c2 0.48-0.52=-0.04). Similarly, since a1 and b1 were 0 and 0 after rounding, we will carryforward 0.21 and 0.31 to a2, b2 giving us a2=0.21+0.21=0.42 and b2=0.31+0.31=0.62 and c2=0.48-0.52=-0.04

Step 3: 
Repeat Step 1 for 2nd elements, which in this case will become round(a2) = round(0.42) =0, round(b2) = round(0.62)=1, round(c2)=round(-0.04) = 0.

Carryforwrd the difference, from a2 -> 0.42, from b2 -> -0.38, from c2 = -0.04 to next element

a3 will become 0.21 + 0.42 = 0.63, b3 will become =0.31-0.38 = -0.07, and c3 will become 0.48 - 0.04 = 0.44

After rounding the 3rd element, a3 round will become 1, b3 -> 0, c3 -> 0

... and so on so forth.

Is there any way we can do this using the all-powerful arrays?

Comment: This would require a stateful arraySequentialReduce function. Currently ClickHouse only has arrrayCumSum for sequenced aggregate, and arrayReduce for unsequenced aggregate. Both are stateless.  It sounds useful to have a function that provides stateful column as an aggregator var though.

Comment: I just noticed that arrayReduce is also sequenced. Maybe you can roll a customized aggregator for this `carry forward` case. See https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2415

Comment: Thanks Amos! If you don't mind, can you please elaborate  on "customized aggregator" I am afraid, I am not following you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a well-suited task for ClickHouse, but you can utilize the fact that an array won't be splitted into two rows and use a custom function to process the array.

The idea is simple. First assemble three arrays into an array of array using `groupArrayForEach`. So

```
[0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21] as a,
[0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31] as b,
[0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48] as c
```

becomes

```
[[0.21, 0.31, 0.48], [0.21, 0.31, 0.48], [0.21, 0.31, 0.48]]
```

Then create a arrayReduce like function that does `Carry Forward Rounding`. Take a look at how arrayReduce is implemented in https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/Functions/arrayReduce.cpp#L169

In fact you don't need an aggregator, a simple loop should be enough.

It would be better if ClickHouse supports stateful lambdas. I'd expect something like this

```
select
arrayCum
(
arr, old_carry =>
    with
     arrayMap(x, y -> x + y, arr, old_carry) as arr,
     arrayEnumerate(arr) as idx,
     arrayReduce('max', arr) as m
     arrayFirstIndex(e -> e = m, arr) as i,
     arrayMap(j -> if(i = j, 1, 0), idx) as rounded,
     arrayMap(x, y -> x - y, arr, rounded) as carry
     --
     rounded, carry
     , arr, arrayMap(x -> 0, arr)
)
from
( select groupArrayForEach(a) arr from data )
```

Comment: Hello Amos, I have learnt so much reading your posts/answers. Specifically, regarding this issue (which is quite old now, but still very much a requirement), we would need little bit of direct help. Would it be possible for us to contact you via email etc.

Comment: @calgs Hi, it's fine. Let's see what I can do about it.

Comment: Well, I guess the first task is to find out my email XD. (tag: easy task)